# ¿no module named pandas?

Tags: python

Estoy usando Anaconda navigator y necesito hacer una funcion que reciba una estructura DataFrame para retornar un diccionario hecho a partir de datos de un csv. Pero tengo un problema y es que cuando hago el `import pandas as pd` me aparece un mensaje que dice no module named pandas. Ya he intentado reinstalar anaconda y usar comandos del cmd pero no he podido solucionarlo y no se que hacer, en especial porque hasta ahora estoy conociendo python.

Comment: ingresa a tu entorno de anaconda y ejecuta `pip list` o `pip show pandas` si no vez nada o vez un error es por que no esta instalado

Comment: @Christian me parece que el no usa pip para instalar modulos, si no anaconda. Pero buena idea igual!

Comment: Gracias miraré entonces, y frente al programa, puedo usar funciones como median u otras para promediar datos del csv para el diccionario?

Comment: lo mejor es que hagas otra pregunta con tu duda, pero de forma rápida te digo que existe el método `mean()` para sacar un promedio

Answer (score 0):

Pandas se debería instalar con los paquetes base de Anaconda. Revisa el detalle de tu instalación a ver si ves esta línea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si aún así no te funciona, ejecuta `conda install pandas` esto desde la línea de comandos del programa que estés usando con el Anaconda Navigator (yo lo he probado en Spyder).

Si nada de esto funciona, te recomiendo desinstalar Python y Anaconda por completo de tu máquina (desintalar, borrar la carpeta de "Archivos de programa" y revisar que se haya quitado de las variables de entorno), ejecutar alguna herramienta para limpiar el registro (en caso de que estés en Windows) y reinstalar.